# No Generate Button for Meta Rig in Object Mode

Tags: rigging

[image: Picture of my model]
I am trying to pose this model with the Human Meta Rig, but I cant' find the "generate" Button. I have searched the internet for hours, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What does the generate button do for you? I mean if you press it, what will happen?

Comment: I just can't find the generate button. It should be under Object Data, but it isn't

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem:

1. Select the *Human(Meta-Rig)* then enter the **Pose Mode**
   [image]
2. Select **Object Data** Tab
   [image]

Now you can see the **Generate Rig** button

Comment: It is stuck in object mode, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the meta rig and re-did it, and it works.